# Exporting GeoPDF using QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf

I'm having issues exporting a georeferenced map from QGIS using version 3.10.4-A coruna. I've tried different (newer) versions of QGIS and also different computers and get the same error.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to export a limited view (approximately 50x50km) of a larger data set (vector data of the whole of Sweden) to a georeferenced PDF in order to view it in map software like "Avenza maps" etc.

**My issues are the following:**

1. The pdf won't display in pdf readers. Adobe reader gives me an error message reading:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly.

2. Slim pdf reader gives me an error message reading:

> #0: Code: PDL::ERR_PDF_SYNTAX Function: Investintech::PDL::DAL::Rendering::Renderer::ProcessOperator_sc_Common
> Line: 7900".

3. Opening the pdf in "Avenza maps" displays the pdf correctly but it is not georeferenced.

**Dataset:**

The dataset I'm using is vector data covering Sweden.

**Here's what I know/ think so far:**

1. QGIS does not report any errors when exporting the pdf (successfully exported layout).
2. My export settings are set to default, however I've tried different settings. These are my default settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXqKl.png
3. PDF export of much smaller vector datasets functions correctly in version 3-10.4 .
4. Opening the PDF in Acrobat reader sometimes loads some features (though far from all of them). You can see an example of this here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMSLy.png
5. I do not believe my computer is the cause since I've tried multiple and get the same error.

What could be the issue?

Comment: One of your layers (usually one with a lot of features and/or attributes) corrupts the file. Using 3.16 this can be avoided by not creating a layered PDF. 3.10 somehow has georeferenced and layers connected, you can't have one without the other.

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know how to create a non-layered geopdf? I cant seem to find that setting.

Comment: I know it's tangential to your question, but beware that Avenza will rasterize your pdf before serving it as a map. You are better off saving and uploading the map as a geoTiff so that you can control the rasterization. In addition, I've had issues with pdfs with partially transparent layers, which then get screwed up in the Avenza rasterization. Again, geoTiff solves the problem.

Comment: What were the precise and detailed steps that you used to produce the map you used to export this troublesome PDF or to produce any PDF that gives the same error?  Please always include errors as formatted text rather than links to pictures of errors.

Answer (score -1):

This is very strange because I have the same problem.
The only reader that reads the file correctly is Foxit, but Acrobat is not.
Sometimes the file is read, but then it loses 1 or 2 layers that are not displayed.
I can read your Test18.pdf complete with Acrobat without errors, but I miss the `Markdata risk` layer. But if you create a non-layered GeoPDF you cannot set layers on or off anymore. So that I think is not the solution.